# Evaluating performance of Neural Network embeddings in kNN classifier

Tags: neural-network, classification, deep-learning, knn, representation

I am solving a classification problem. I train my unsupervised neural network for a set of entities (using skip-gram architecture).

The way I evaluate is to search k nearest neighbours *for each point in validation data*, *from training data*. I take weighted sum (weights based on distance) of labels of nearest neighbours and use that score of each point of validation data.

**Observation** - As I increase the number of epochs (`model1` - 600 epochs, `model 2`- 1400 epochs and `model 3` - 2000 epochs), my AUC improves at smaller values of `k` but saturates at the similar values.

What could be a possible explanation of this behaviour?

[image]

[[Reposted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193779/evaluating-performance-neural-network-embeddings-in-knn-classifier) from CrossValidated]

Comment: I am trying to classify customer reviews in two categories. Embeddings are trained using sentence2vec. I have written a custom kNN classifier for hadoop.

Comment: Could it just be that there is not enough seperability between the two classes? For example, if this were some type of sentiment analysis then we often experience double negative expressions that can upset a naive classifier.

Comment: If `model3` is better at classifying such cases, wouldn't it have better AUC than `model1`?

Comment: What is the population size of your data and is it equally balanced between the two classes? It feels that model3 is doing a better job at classifying, which is apparent with low k. However, all models are benefiting from skewed/unbalanced data with larger k. Can we rule this out?

Comment: @JohnWakefield Training dataset is about 50000 examples, with about 1200 positives. Can skewness be responsible for all models behaving similarly at larger k? In that case, shouldn't results be the worst at those values of k?

Comment: The way to eliminate the negative skew theory is to adjust your testing regime to include more "positives" - maybe even 100% positives. If there is a bias towards false negatives, this would then be easy to spot with a worsening of the AUC.

Answer (score 0):

To cross check if imbalanced classes are an issue, try fitting a SVM model. If that gives a better classification(possible if your ANN is not very deep) it may be concluded that classes should be balanced first.

Also, try some kernel functions to check if this transformation makes data linearly separable?